# PDO - SQLServer change maximum data limit

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sqlsrv

I have Windows Server + MSSQL2017 + php7.3.13 + PDO(pdo_sqlsrv and sqlsrv)

```
PHPInfo: memory_limit=16M  /  both buffer_max_kb_size=10240
```

If I get less than 600kb data from DB this code works fine.
If I want to get more strings I receive nothing. No errors. Fast execution and white screen.
I've seen some advises to increase buffer_max_kb-params but in my phpinfo I see that they set to 10M.
My max data-size is 2M ( to measure data-size I execute the query in MSSM and save result into text)
So there must be another option but what is it? Nothing could found (

Code:

```
try{

    $conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:Server= $host ; Database = $db ", $user, $pwd);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "select * from tabl";
    $stmt = $conn->query($sql);
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NAMED);
    }
catch(Exception $e){
    die(print_r($e));
}
```

Comment: A possible [configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/cursor-types-pdo-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver15#pdo_sqlsrv-and-client-side-cursors).

Comment: If use SQLSRV_CURSOR_BUFFERED then I have to increase buffer_max_kb a bit . Otherwise there is a error "Memory limit of 10240 KB exceeded for buffered query". But nothing return as well. Even print $stmt->rowCount(); doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that I measured data in text and was sure that it is a small volume. But using SQLSRV_CURSOR_BUFFERED helped me to find out that data size is much more.
Finally I used ini_set('memory_limit', '256M') and it works.

But this is not understandable - how 2M of data needs minimum 200M of memory?